# Font change in RadGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I have created a `Telerik Windows Form Application` Project, and Then I added a `RadGridView`.

[image]

But it seems font changing does not affect columns and rows and so many others.
I should change the theme to `ControlDefault` to get the font affect.

[image]

[image]

This problem is also appearing on `RadButtons`. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please have in mind that for some controls (like RadLabel), it is enough to set the Font property, while for others (like RadGridView), you will need to introduce this setting in a formatting event, e.g. the [CellFormatting](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/cells/formatting-cells)/[ViewCellFormatting](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/cells/formatting-cells) events that RadGridView offers:

```
        Font f = new Font("Arial", 10, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);
    private void RadGridView1_ViewCellFormatting(object sender, CellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CellElement.Font = f;
    }
```

I would recommend you to have a look at the following KB article: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/knowledge-base/change-the-font

Comment: so why is it working on `RadGridView` while the theme is default?

Comment: The different themes that the Telerik UI for WinForms suite offers provide different style settings to the internal elements. Hence, the different themes apply different styles from where comes the difference. In one theme the font may be applied to grid elements on each cell element, while on another this font may be inherited from the parent. That is why the recommended approach is to use the formatting event.